# mysql missing update information

Tags: mysql, database

ive got problem with update.
here is mysql query.log

```
 25474 Query     UPDATE db_mail4u.dMailerQueue 
                 SET mailid = '1Rj6eb-0005bG-ED'
                 where DeliveryId = '131' and Email = 'mail4u@mail4u.com.ua'
                 LIMIT 1

 25491 Query     UPDATE db_mail4u.dMailerQueue
                 SET Status = 'D'
                 WHERE mailid = '1Rj6eb-0005bG-ED'
                 LIMIT 1
```

after this there is OK with mailid update and  no update to Status. 
there is no error or something like this.

How can i debug this? or fix or what to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

is `mailid` a primary key for `db_mail4u.dMailerQueue` table? if it is, why do have `LIMIT 1` on your query? but if not, maybe the first record found is only the one being updated.

try to count if how many records of `mailid` ('1Rj6eb-0005bG-ED') are there in the table `db_mail4u.dMailerQueue`

Comment: limit is set to 1 to prevent database corruption from incorect testing. mailid and another columt are uniq key.

Comment: Thanks for help, we ve find a problem. We've got race condition.